# which database does java supports by default

Tags: java, database, javadb

In a recent interview I was asked "which database does java support by default" . I couldn't provide a proper answer to this question as i really don't know which one it is as I have worked with mysql database mostly which requires an additional driver called connector/j to be added to the lib folder and subsequently added to the build path so for that I ruled it out of the answer. Then again which one it is then Derby Db ,Oracle(Which I don't think it is) or any other database?

Can anyone please provide some insight into this?

Comment: It has always amazed me that so many interviews seem to turn into exams in random trivia.

Comment: couldn't find anything on google ?

Comment: I was confused with what i got in google cause as i mentioned no 1 mentioned it properly ..mostly it was about some native and types of drivers kinda crap :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is JavaDB :

> Java DB is Oracle's supported distribution of the Apache Derby open source database. It supports standard ANSI/ISO SQL through the JDBC and Java EE APIs. Java DB is included in the JDK.

Full documentation is available [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/).

Comment: Is java db the same as apache derby db with just the tag of oracle or is it different and also is it open source like derby db??

Comment: It's the same binary. See the FAQ question here : http://developers.sun.com/javadb/features/faqs.jsp#1q2 (Is Java DB a fork of Apache Derby?)

Answer (score 5):

**Answer 1**: Java supports all databases that provide [jdbc](/questions/tagged/jdbc) driver. All major RDBMS databases have at least one available.

**Answer 2**: Java natively supports [Java DB](http://developers.sun.com/javadb), included in the JDK.

Comment: Does it include support for inbuilt type 4 drivers??